# IDTSLogging does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime'

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have a problem with Visual Studio Professional 2019.

> CS0234: The type or namespace name 'IDTSLogging' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I tried to remove reference and add it from 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS' but it doesn't work and I cannot build the solution.

I've also installed sql server data tools but nothing work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you would like to solve IDTSLogging's lack of assembly

references.

You can try to install nugget package ->MicrosoftSqlServerManagedDTS to solve the problem.

Like the following:

[image]